# Do I need to install mssql before I can use mssql.so with php on unix?

Tags: php, sql-server, unix

I didn't install any MSSQL instance on my localhost that runs windows. I just used the xampp package and uncommented the modules used for mssql. The mssql server resides on another Windows Server so I believe I only needed a simple connector module.

I hoped that it would be the same for Unix. But whenever I open my site on the unix production server, (i use codeigniter btw) the logs tell me it stops script execution after Database Driver Class Initialized.

I am not really familiar on installing apache and friends on unix and I wasn't responsible on how the server was set-up. But it turns out that there is no mssql.so found on the php modules directory so i tried to google for one.

While the forums are telling me to just compile the script, I couldn't just do that simply as I have no write access to the server and plus it seems upon installation of php, phpize didn't get installed with it too.

Hope someone can shed light to me regarding this. I think its just easier if I can get a mssql.so for PHP 4.4.4

Comment: having a hard time seeing any programming content...

Comment: Have you checked documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php

Comment: If you'd provided details of the versin of Linux you are running, the version of PHP and whether it was installed from source or from packages then we might have been able to give more specific direction

Answer (score 2):

you will probably need freetds. mssql.so is just a wrapper, not a driver.

regards,
/t